# CSS triangle side of a button with round on right?

Tags: css

I've tried to create a button like this in CSS and the pointy part of the button not as pointy?

Here is CSS:

```
.home_icon { width: 40px; height: 25px; margin-left:10px; margin-top:8px; background: #FFCC05 url(../images/home_icon.svg) no-repeat 12px 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 11px 5px 5px 11px/17px 5px 5px 17px; -moz-border-radius: 11px 5px 5px 11px/17px 5px 5px 17px; border-radius: 11px 5px 5px 11px/17px 5px 5px 17px;}
```

Can anyone have a solution? I'm prepared to change the css code as long I've 'Equilateral' triangle of the pointy (on left) of a button?

[image: align top]
<sub>(source: [kerrydeaf.com](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/css.png))</sub>

**UPDATE:**
Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alma/eBtY4/1/

Comment: You *want* the pointy end to be *less-pointy*, or it's not pointy *enough*? Can you share a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, live demo so we can see what you're working with (HTML, CSS and the actual image)?

Comment: Like this as above, or similiar is acceptable. It not about more or less pointy. I've a graphic example and that should be enough / self explanatory of what I'm looking for?

Comment: Same one as above - http://jsfiddle.net/alma/eBtY4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this

```
.home_icon
{
 width: 120px;
 height: 80px;
 background:red;
 position: relative;
-moz-border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
-webkit-border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
 border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
}
.home_icon:before
{ 
content:"";
position:absolute;
right: 100%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 40px solid transparent;
border-right: 26px solid red;
border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: That is fantastic, this is what I'm looking for. Would it possible to have width: 40px; height: 25px; as an option?

Comment: Here is a updated jsfiddle.net/alma/USezL/3 The yellow is perfect. I've tried the hover cyan colour and it doesn't work on a triangle part?

Comment: I've updated jsiddles as above. I've no luck with cyan hover on a triangle part?