# making a specific form with css after before

Tags: css, geometry

I try to have this result only with css. I prefere to make it css instead of using an image because i will have many div of this king but with different angles of width.

[The shape i'm trying to have](http://cecinestpasunsite.com/test/shape.jpg)

You'll find here what i have tried... but with no success...

```
.bloc1:before{
content: "";
background-color: #123456;
width : 27px;
height : 27px;
margin-top : 10px;
transform: rotate(45deg);
 }

 .bloc1 {
 background-color: #000000;
 width : 107px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top : 8px;
 height : 19px;
 color : #FFFFFF;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 12px;
position: relative;
}

 .bloc1:after{
 content: "";
 background-color: #123456;
 width : 27px;
 height : 27px;
 margin-top : 10px;
 transform: rotate(45deg) ;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wBNry/

For you, what's the best method to do that ?

So many thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS triangle side of a button with round on right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321558/css-triangle-side-of-a-button-with-round-on-right)

Comment: Specifically, see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/USezL/1/

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this method, but here, the angle of the left extremity is not 90deg, it's more. I try to have an exact 90deg angle. Any idea ?

Comment: Play with the `border-right` property of the `:before` block until you find the right angle, maybe with the help of trigonometry.

Comment: Many Thanks :) I feel very stupid for not having found this idea... Thanks again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wBNry/4/)

```
.bloc1:before,
.bloc1:after {
    content: "";
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border: 15px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}

.bloc1 {
    background-color: #000000;
    width : 107px;
    text-align: center;
    height : 30px;
    color : #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    margin:50px;
}
.bloc1:before {
    right:100%;
    border-right-color:red;
}

.bloc1:after{
    left:100%;
    border-left-color:red;
}
```

Comment: A thousand thank you, it's really nice to have make a jsfiddle. It's perfect :)